# What's the difference between these 2 SQL query involving round() and ceiling ()?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT      ROUND(CEILING(36.3) / 4,2)

SELECT      ROUND(37 / 4,2)
```

The first query returns 9.25. The second query returns 9.
Ceiling(36.3) would have returned 37. Why would there be such differences then?

Comment: This looks somewhat unexpected me, but in any case, which is your actual _database_ (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres) ?

Comment: You are obviously using a DBMS that applies primary school division (aka integer division) when the operands are integers. `36.3` is a decimal number, andd so are its calculation results. `CEILING(36.3)` is `37.0`. And `37.0 / 4 = 9.25` as opposed to `37 / 4 = 9 remainder 1`.

Comment: This is why you should tag SQL requests always with the DBMS you are using. Some DBMS apply integer division while others divide regularly. If you tag the request with your DBMS, people who know the DBMS can give you the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is due to the return type from operations. When you call Ceiling on any number or expression, the return type is of same type as the expression.

Let's look at the first one:

```
Ceiling(36.3) -> returns a decimal
```

This means that the division operation is also done on decimals which means you get a decimal result and thus could be rounded.

In the second statement, you are dividing 2 integers which would also result in a integer result (just the quotient). Thus the value will only be 9.

```
SELECT      ROUND(CEILING(36.3) / 4,2) -- select round(decimal/int,int) => select round(decimal, int)

SELECT      ROUND(37 / 4,2) -- select round(int/int,int) => select round(int, int)
```

You would get similar result when you do this:

```
SELECT      ROUND((CEILING(36.3) / 4),2)

SELECT      ROUND((cast(37 as decimal(10,2)) / 4),2)
```

Comment: This is true for those DBMS that apply integer division when the operands are integers. Many DBMS don't do that. They divide properly, no matter what type. (And I consider this safer, as a column change from decimal to integer or vice versa in the data model doesn't break queries.)

Comment: Indeed. You are correct. But looking at the question, I figure their DB is operand sensitive.